# Oracle: Paginating LISTAGG()

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I am trying to pull a set of quoted UUIDs from a database, and am using `LISTAGG()` to do so, thus:

```sql
SELECT
  COUNT(uuid) "Entries",
  '( ' || LSITAGG( DISTINCT '''' || uuid || '''', ', ' ON OVERFLOW ERROR ) || ' )' "UUIDs"
FROM
  table_with_uuids
/* 
WHERE
  criteria omitted for brevity
 */
;
```

This works perfectly well, but there are some use-cases where the number of UUIDs presented creates a string that is too long (hence the usage of `ON OVERFLOW ERROR`). In these cases, I would like to iterate `LISTAGG()` over batches of returned results.  I feel like I am on the right track with something like this:

```sql
WITH active_uuids AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    uuid
  FROM
    table_with_uuids
  -- [ WHERE clause omitted ]
  OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 99 ROWS ONLY -- Fetching 100 will overflow LISTAGG
)
SELECT
  count(uuid) "Entries",
  '( ' || LISTAGG( '''' || uuid || '''', ', ' ON OVERFLOW ERROR ) || ' )' "UUIDs"
FROM
  active_uuids
;
```

But I don't want to have to manually increment the `OFFSET` until I run out of records.  Ideally I would be able to in one shot get an aggregated list in batches of all of the returned records.  Is this doable?

(My access to this DB is limited; I cannot `CREATE` views, temporary tables, functions, or any of that fun stuff for Reasons).

Comment: I may look into that, but presuming `XMLAGG()` outputs XML, I'd then have to convert from XML to the format I need in the first place.  Worse come to worst, I could abstract this to a shell script that does a `SELECT COUNT [...]` and automagically does manual `OFFSET` iteration in successively generated queries, but I was hoping to be able to do it all in SQL for convenience's sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY CEIL(ROWNUM/99)` to "paginate" the UUIDs into groups of 99 rows and then aggregate those rows. Additional "pages" will be in the next group(s) so you will get multiple rows:

```sql
WITH active_uuids (uuid) AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         uuid
  FROM   table_with_uuids
  ORDER BY uuid             -- Optional
)
SELECT count(uuid) AS Entries,
       '( '
       || LISTAGG( '''' || uuid || '''', ', ' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM)
       || ' )' AS UUIDs
FROM   active_uuids
GROUP BY CEIL(ROWNUM/99);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zY1-Qdk_)